# Вывод результатов

Tags: массивы, delphi

Как вывести результаты в таблицу из массива вида:

```
type
 TArray = record
  Str1, Str2, Str3: String;
 MyArray = array[0..100] of TArray
```

В первом столбце таблицы должны быть строки из поля Str1, во втором столбце из поля Str2, а в третьем Str3!

Answer (score 3):

Неужели на этот вопрос в гугле нет ответа? Даже нажав `StringGrid.<Ctrl+Пробел>` можно было найти подходящее свойство.

Изучайте [StringGrid.Cells](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cells)